# How does XmlReader.Read() work?

Tags: c#, .net, stream, xmlreader

I am getting huge amounts of XML data from an external API.

Originally I used something like this:

```
string uri = "http://wwww.sometld.com/api";
XDocument xmlDoc = new XDocument();

HttpWebRequest client = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
client.Timeout = 2100000;//35 minutes
WebResponse apiResponse = client.GetResponse();

Stream receivedStream = apiResponse.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(receivedStream);

string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

I ran into problems because sometimes the XML documents were so large that I was running into "out of memory" exceptions (2-3GB files!).

So I changed my process to use something like this instead:

```
string uri = "http://wwww.sometld.com/api";
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;

string xmldocstring = "";

using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(uri, settings))
{
    reader.ReadStartElement("DATASET");

    while (!reader.EOF)
    {
        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
        {
            try
            {
                XElement elR = XNode.ReadFrom(reader) as XElement;

                //parse the xml here and do stuff with it

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Log.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            reader.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

I understand how the first one works...you make a request, get back a response from the server and you parse it into an `XDocument`.

But how does the second one work? How can you only get back one piece of the response at a time? Doesn't the whole response come back at once? How does this work? How does `XmlReader.Read` only read one line of the response at a time?

Is the whole response being held in memory and `XmlReader` is just reading from that? Or is each `XmlReader.Read` call actually fetching something from the server?

Comment: The response will come back as fast as the client asks for it. There are some internal buffers, but once these are full then everything in the steam chain will "hold off" until there is new space available in the buffer - then everything asks for (or allows) data from the upstream again. If you look at the network connection, you'll see that it stays open for the duration of the XmlReader. If you add in delays to the program you'll see the network speed vary.

Comment: I guess I don't understand how this works. I thought the client DID ask for it...it sends a request, and gets a response - isn't that how this works? Can you elaborate?

Comment: HTTP is a [*stream*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_(computing)). While the stream can be materialized (e.g. everything read until EOF and turned into a string), it can also be consumed as required. That is what the XmlReader is doing - it's only consuming as much as is asked for. It does *not* read from the underlying data-source until it needs more.

Comment: I don't understand how that works. The server is only sending back bits and pieces? Is there something I can read that explains it?

Comment: The HTTP stream a result of using [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) as the transport. TCP ensures that data isn't lost, and one of the methods ways that it does this is the client must acknowledge a packet from the server - after which time the server can move another packet onto the wire. If an HTTP stream is consumed in C# then it will end up using the native network API which in turn deal with the TCP protocol; as the C# (via XmlReader) empties the network buffers, the network API tells the server it can send more data.

Comment: As such, with some slack provided by various buffers, the data only leaves the stream source (server) as fast as it is consumed the stream consumer (XmlReader.Read) and so it doesn't pile up anywhere. (Also note, that even with *huge buffers*, the CPU processing is *much faster* than a network connection and it can liekly consume it as fast as provided here: add in some `Sleep`s to see the stream backup, although it still won't consume terribly much memory.)

Comment: Ok...interesting. I thought the server sends the data in multiple pieces and it arrives randomly and it gets pieced together at the end. But maybe that is lower on the stack. Is there somewhere you can point me to read more about this?  Can you make this an answer?

Comment: That is done at the TCP layer - where pieces are sent in packets. HTTP itself doesn't provide a stream in this same sense (it does support pipelining and range requests, but those are different) but rather utilizes the underlying transport.